# Fade in / Ease down sticky header

Tags: jquery, css, easing

A client of mine is using a sticky header that kicks in after a certain distance has been scrolled.

They now want the header to fade in and slide down into position as oppose to just "appearing" as it does now.

jQuery isn't my strong suit so any help would be great.

Here is [the URL in question](http://stage.purenine.com/details-page/)  and here is the current jQuery used for the sticky header;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var headerheight = $("header").height();
    var header = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (header > height-75 ) {
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
        $('body').css("padding-top", headerheight);
        $('.sticky').css('top', 0);
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('body').css("padding-top", 0);
        $('header').css('top', 25);
    }

});
```

Comment: You could also try adding `transition:all 300ms ease;` to the `sticky` CSS class. It doesn't fade, but the effect is interesting. If you added `$('header').css('opacity', 0').addClass('sticky').css('opacity', 1);`, it might also pull off the fading. Try it and see -- really simple addition :)

Comment: @Chris -- not cross-browser compatible... But could be:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202963/making-css-transition-effects-work-in-all-browsers

I still think using jQuery would be better to handle all cases and keep within the framework of what's being used. Easing is more JS than CSS in activity type, in my opinion.

Comment: @digitalextremist The intention was to try offer a suggestion, not provide a detailed and formal answer -- otherwise, I'd have posted an answer. I simply wanted to put CSS on the table, if the OP wants to explore that route, they can. As for easing being the role of javascript, I don't think it matters but I would lean toward it being the job of CSS, which is meant to handle presentation formatting. If easing were a primary JS activity, there would be something for it built into the language rather than relying on an additional library or writing thousands of lines of vanilla script.

Comment: No disrespect intended @Chris. CSS3 in general is not a given for browsers out there, with the JS comment being secondary as to the role of each tool in the creation of an aesthetic that is transforming. Please don't take my shortness as a disagreement, but a rapid-fire follow-up to your rightful gesturing to CSS's *latest* powers.

Comment: @digitalextremist No offense taken -- we're typing in character-limited comment boxes, not having a real conversation :p

Answer (score 0):

If the below fix doesn't just drop in, the concept solves your issue and future instances where 'easing' is needed. We'll disappear the element and cause it to reappear gracefully.

Specifically, before `addClass('sticky')` do: `$('header').hide()` and after you did all your aesthetic magic to it, do `$('header').fadeIn('fast')` ... then undue that for your scroll-back case.

**Sample:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var headerheight = $("header").height();
    var header = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (header > height-75 ) {
        $('header').hide();
        $('header').addClass('sticky');
        $('body').css("padding-top", headerheight);
        $('.sticky').css('top', 0);
        $('header').fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
        $('header').fadeOut('fast');
        $('header').removeClass('sticky');
        $('body').css("padding-top", 0);
        $('header').css('top', 25);
        $('header').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

That will on the one hand be quick, but on the other hand be elegant and feel fluid. Otherwise, great looking design.